# Desconsider number after dot

Tags: java, android, type-conversion

I want to keep only the number before dot, what comes after I don't want to. For example:

```
double x = 5.6
int y = 5 // the part before dot
```

For this purpose I have the following code:

```
SeekBar tipSeekBar;
EditText tipAmountET;
double tipAmount;
tipAmount = (tipSeekBar.getProgress()) * .01;               
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);
Number number;
number = format.parse(String.valueOf(tipAmount));
double d = number.doubleValue();
String resultado = String.valueOf(d * 100);
tipAmountET.setText(resultado);
```

I tried to use the split on `resultado`, but it gives me the exception `ArrayOutOfBoundsException`. Like this, before the last line:

```
String[] split = resultado.split(".");
tipAmountET.setText(split[0]);
```

Comment: `resultado.split("\\.")`....

Comment: double d = 5.6;
  int y = (int)d;

Comment: You can simply cast it. Casting a floating point number to an integer results the part "before the dot" (unless it's out of range, then it limits to the max or min value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**y will be equally 5 after this conversion:**

```
double x = 5.6
int y = (int) x;
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't just casting it give you what you want?

```
double x = 5.6;
int y = (int)x;
System.out.println(y);
```